# A short form of compact()?

Tags: php

Right now my controllers does this:

```
$topics = ['lol'];
$users = ['oh baby'];

return Api::json(compact('topics', 'users'));
```

and outputs:

```
{"topics":["lol"],"users":["oh baby"]}
```

I write this a lot and would like to shorten it for typing's sake.

Api.php class: 
https://gist.github.com/clouddueling/edc4692771713d0fdcf9

Is there a way to do this?

```
$topics = ['lol'];
$users = ['oh baby'];

return Api::json('topics', 'users');
```

and still outputs:

```
{"topics":["lol"],"users":["oh baby"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning into a bunch of different variables, why not just assign into keys of an associative array?

```
$data['topics'] = ['lol'];
$data['users'] = ['oh baby'];

return Api::json($data);
```

Then you don't have to awkwardly use `compact` or some approximation of `compact` at all.